# C++ & Matlab: executable crashes when launched from Matlab (C++ allocation unsupported ?)

Tags: c++, matlab, crash, executable, allocation

I'm developing a C++ project on Code::Blocks using the GNU GCC Compiler (on Windows).

The project is composed of 5 files and runs perfectly using Code::Blocks. However when I try to run the executable (found in the `debug` directory) from Matlab it crashes directly. From my point of view, it is because of the memory allocation which is not well recognized in Matlab (xx = new struct[int]).

It was observed that if the lines containing the allocation are removed (`new struct` and `new vec`), the executable can be run from Matlab. (The size of the structure and vectors must be decided in `int main()` )

Here is the code: basically, it initializes several vectors (embedded in a structure) and each vector has a dimension of (x,y,z)*nbrcompon.

(Please, do not tell me about using `#include <vector>`)

Main.cpp

```
#define EASYDYNMBSMAIN   

#include <iostream>
#include "Vectors.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

nbrvec=3;
nbrcompon=2;
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

InitVec();
cout << VectorArray[2].velocity[0] << endl; // must be commented to run from Matlab
return 0;
}
```

Vectors.cpp

```
#include "Vectors.h"

void InitVec()
{
   if (nbrvec>0)
   {
       VectorArray=new structvectors[nbrvec]; // must be commented to run from Matlab
       for(int ivec=0; ivec< nbrvec; ivec++ )
       {
           VectorArray[ivec].velocity= new vec[nbrcompon]; // must be commented to run from Matlab
       }

       VectorArray[2].velocity[0].put(2.03,3.2,36.2); // must be commented to run from Matlab
   }
}
```

Vectors.h

```
#ifndef VECTORS_H_INCLUDED
#define VECTORS_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#include "Components.h"

struct structvectors
{
      vec *velocity;
};

#ifdef EASYDYNMBSMAIN
#define EASYDYNSIMMAIN
structvectors *VectorArray=0;
int nbrvec=0;
int nbrcompon=0;
#else
extern structvectors *VectorArray;
extern int nbrvec;
extern int nbrcompon;
#endif
void InitVec();

#endif // VECTORS_H_INCLUDED
```

Components.cpp

```
#include <math.h>
#include "Components.h"

vec::vec(double xinit, double yinit, double zinit)
  {
  x=xinit; y=yinit; z=zinit;
  }

  void vec::put(double xcoord, double ycoord, double zcoord)
  {
  x=xcoord; y=ycoord; z=zcoord;
  }

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, vec v)
  {
  stream << setw(15) << v.x << " " << setw(15) << v.y
 << setw(15) << v.z;
  return stream;
  }

istream &operator>>(istream &stream, vec &v)
  {
  stream >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
  return stream;
  }
```

Components.h

```
#ifndef COMPONENTS_H_INCLUDED
#define COMPONENTS_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

// Definition of vector components

class vec
{
    public :
        double x,y,z;
        vec(double xinit=0.0, double yinit=0.0, double zinit=0.0);
        void put(double xcoord, double ycoord , double zcoord);
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, vec v);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &stream, vec &v);
};
#endif // COMPONENTS_H_INCLUDED
```

The simple Matlab code that runs the executable

```
clear all
close all
clc
system('VecProject.exe &')
```

Any suggestion to solve the issue ?

Thank you in advance for your answer ;-)

Comment: Looks like reading the documentation might help here https:/mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcalloc.html

Comment: You have a stand-alone executable, that does not at all link to MATLAB? And you are starting it with `system` or `!`? And it crashes? But it doesn't crash when you start if from `cmd.exe`? That's weird at best. You probably have some memory management error, which causes trouble when executed as a child process of MATLAB but not as a child process of `cmd.exe`. That will be fun to find!

Comment: Wait, `new vec[nbrcompon];` in Vectors.cpp. Do you define `EASYDYNMBSMAIN` when compiling? If so, `nbrcompon==0`, so you're trying to `new` a 0-sized array. That will crash. And if it doesn't elsewhere you'll be accessing elements that were not allocated (out-of-bounds indexing). That often crashes also.

Comment: Some of the convoluted nature of this code seems to come from the global variables. They certainly made it harder for me to figure out, having to look all around for `nbrvec` etc. It's usually considered good practice to avoid global variables whenever possible.

Comment: I do define #define EASYDYNMBSMAIN at the beginning of the main() but the executable found in the debug directory of Code::Blocks crashes when launched by Matlab. I'm starting it with "system" in Matlab and it does not crash with cmd.exe.

Comment: @H.Nam Yes, it's likely that you write out of bounds, and overwrite something important when launched from MATLAB. Try running your program under a debugger that checks for out-of-bounds writes, such as Valgrind.

Comment: Also, please please pretty please, write `InitVec` to take `nbrvec` and `nbrcompon` as input arguments, instead of declaring them as global variables. Declarations that change when a preprocessor variable is defined is also terribly error prone and confusing.

Comment: Oh, and have the function *return* `VectorArray`, don't use a global variable for that either.

Comment: Is there anyway you can convert this c/c++ program to a .mex file instead of an. exe?

Comment: I have never played with .mex file... The idea was to keep the low level programming in c/c++ for a fast usage. Are .mex files as fast as a c/c++ program ?